# Kimono - troubleshooting login in windows 10

Tags: authentication, windows-10, kimono

I am new to Kimono and though I know it will no longer be supported, I am considering it since it is free and appears to be very intuitive. I was just running through the tutorials and when it told me to save the scraper it brought be to a login window. I don't know why I would need to log in since it is a stand-alone app. I tried to register anyway, but it did nothing. Under the help topic for "troubleshooting log in" there is a link for a discussion relating to Windows 10, which is my platform, but that link is broken. When I searched online Kimono help for "Windows 10" it produced nothing additional.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Joel

Answer (score 0):

I'm a user of the Kimono desktop application after migrating from the now defunct web service. I have had no issues while using it on both Windows 8 or Windows 10 so far.

Probably three small things to check as it's not clearly stated:

- The desktop client is now the only way to run APIs. A login is not required unless you wish to download existing APIs from an existing Kimono account.
- Make sure you're creating APIs with the desktop chrome extension, not the old web-based Kimono extension.
  [kimono desktop Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hmeapcbkmejjfmphikcpgbgakfnjcade)
- The desktop application must be running before using the chrome extension to create APIs. This is because it acts as a local web service.

Once you've checked these, let us know how you go.

Comment: Your tips were very helpful after some further experimentation. But I got stuck when I tried to go back and edit my existing API. I responded to your note on March 14 in the form of an "answer" (probably a mistake) because a comment is limited to 500 characters. I thought you would get my questions. I appreciate your invitation to let you know how it went, and hope you will respond to my March 17 "answer."

Comment: Hey, yeah, I don't get notified on other answers. 
When it comes to editing APIs, since I use Authenticated APIs, it never works for me anyway since it won't launch in incognito mode automatically. I just did a test though with a standard API and I'm not having any issues at all Editing the test API. Existing fields are still present and I don't need to manually launch the extension. Unless I can replicate the issue, I can't think of what may be causing it, sorry. Maybe relaunch chrome (type chrome://restart in url) and open then close the extension once before trying to edit an API. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

@Bradley I figured out it insisted I register/login because I was in the tutorial. Apparently the tutorial hasn't been updated to remove the mandatory log in screen. Your tips helped me realize the tutorial isn't an actual session of the desktop app. After puzzling this out I had no problem building & saving my own API.

But...I got stuck when I tried to go back and edit and finish my API. I tried to follow the instructions in the help menu. I opened the desktop app, opened my API then clicked on the [Edit] button. It switched to my browser and opened up the target URL. It gave me no hint what I was supposed to do next, so I opened the chrome extension. But there are no "properties" (or what I would usually call fields or table columns). I don't know how to load the API into chrome.

Thanks for your patience and advice.

Joel